# Get new in put values in a row using App script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**How do I get the new input values in google sheet using App Script. I currently get the values when I specify which cells, but I want it to be dynamic. Please help me.**

```
function getValuesinSheet(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange("B1").setValue("Email");
sheet.getRange("A1").setValue("Amount");
sheet.getRange("C1").setValue("Phone Number");
sheet.getRange("D1").setValue("Email Subject");
sheet.getRange("E1").setValue("Message");
var amount = parseInt(sheet.getRange("A2").getValues())  ;
var email = String(sheet.getRange("B2").getValues());
var snumber = String(sheet.getRange("C2").getValues());
var esubject = String(sheet.getRange("D2").getValues()) ;
var emessage = String(sheet.getRange("E2").getValues());
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to achieve? I did not fully understand the question. Do you want to get the value of the cell that is being modified in a specific row? I would appreciate if you could provide a sample output

Comment: Hi, My problem is I want to get the values of the new input cells in a row. How could I do that? Please help me. Thank you

Comment: @RonM: Yes that's what I'm pointing. Sorry for bad english

Comment: No problem, I already got your concern. Just want to ask if you really want the whole row values or just until column E?

Comment: @RonM until column E. Yes. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

### (Option 1)

You can use [onEdit Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite), to execute an apps script function every time a cell is being modified to read/modify your sheets.

**Sample Code:**

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = e.source; //Get the spreadsheet
  var cell = e.range; //Get the range of the edited cell
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); //Get the modified sheet
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var col = cell.getColumn();
  
  //valid cell are within A2:E. If row ==1 or col > 5 do nothing
  if(row==1 || col > 5){
    return;
  }

  //Get the current row's first 5 columns
  //Change 2-d array to 1-d array using flat()
  var rowValues = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5).getDisplayValues().flat();


  if(rowValues.filter(String).length == 5){
    Logger.log("DO SOMETHING")
    var amount = parseInt(rowValues[0]);
    var email = rowValues[1];
    var snumber = rowValues[2];
    var esubject = rowValues[3];
    var emessage = rowValues[4];
    Logger.log(amount);
    Logger.log(email);
    Logger.log(snumber);
    Logger.log(esubject);
    Logger.log(emessage);
  }

}
```

**What it does?**

1. Get the active sheet and active cell using the [onEdit() events object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
2. Get the active cell's row and column index (apps script used one-based as index)
3. Check if modified cell is within A2:E range, by checking row and column index
4. Get the current row values from column A:E using [Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) and [Range.getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

> I used [Range.getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues), since it will return a 2-d array of string. I noticed that you expect your inputs as a string and you plan to convert the amount to int using parseInt()

5. Use [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to convert 2-d array to 1-d array
6. Check the array if all the columns are not empty using [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), if array length is 5. Then all data in the row is complete

**Note:**

You can remove the condition in Step 6 if you want to process the current row's column A-E values even if some data are empty.

You can also remove the condition in Step 3 based on your preference. I just included that so that the succeeding process will only be executed when cell being modified are within A2:E

**Additional Information**

If you are new with [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), you cannot debug your code by running it in the Apps Script Editor. If you want to debug your code, you need to modify a specific cell in your sheet then check the latest logs in the Executions tab.

**Example:**

[image]

---

### (Option 2)

If you don't prefer to use onEdit() Simple trigger. You can just use [getActiveCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactivecell) to get the current selected cell row and column index

**Sample Code:**

```
function getRowValues(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Get the spreadsheet
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell(); //Get the range of the edited cell
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); //Get the modified sheet
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var col = cell.getColumn();
  
  //valid cell are within A2:E. If row ==1 or col > 5 do nothing
  if(row==1 || col > 5){
    return;
  }

  //Get the current row's first 5 columns
  //Change 2-d array to 1-d array using flat()
  var rowValues = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5).getDisplayValues().flat();


  if(rowValues.filter(String).length == 5){
    Logger.log("DO SOMETHING")
    var amount = parseInt(rowValues[0]);
    var email = rowValues[1];
    var snumber = rowValues[2];
    var esubject = rowValues[3];
    var emessage = rowValues[4];
    Logger.log(amount);
    Logger.log(email);
    Logger.log(snumber);
    Logger.log(esubject);
    Logger.log(emessage);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I got error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined"

Comment: as mentioned in the additional information, you cannot run this function using the Run button in the Apps Script Editor since the event object e is not defined. If you want to test this you need to modify a specific cell in the sheet and check the latest log in the execution tab

Comment: I added an example image. When you run the function in your editor the function will fail. But if it was run automatically using simple trigger, it will pass.

Comment: I added option 2 if you don't prefer using onEdit(). In option 2, you just need to select a specific cell in your sheet and run the function in your apps script editor